# Игнорирование имени пакета при запуске java из командной строки

Tags: java, makefile

Мне приходит файл с исходным кодом Java класса, например:

```java
class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello'w");
    }
}
```

или

```java
package some.packa.ge;

class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello'w");
    }
}
```

Я его копирую в какую-то временную папку `tmp/`, пытаюсь скомпилировать и запустить следующим make'ом

```
all: compile run

compile:
    @javac A.java

run:
    @java A
```

Соответсвенно класс без заданного пакета запускается и работает, а вот с пакетом нет, просит поместить его в директории `some/packa/ge`. Вопрос собственно в том, возможно ли запустить файл с пакетом без создания папок? Если нет, то как сделать make так, что бы он работал как на файлах с пакетом, так и без?

Comment: Как вариант - удалить package до компиляции.

Comment: Писать make-файлы для компилятора пустая трата времени, затраченного на компиляцию.